# Amazon Cloudfront with S3. Access Denied

Tags: permissions, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

We're trying to distribute out S3 buckets via Cloudfront but for some reason the only response is an AccessDenied XML document like the following:

```
<Error>
    <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
    <Message>Access Denied</Message>
    <RequestId>89F25EB47DDA64D5</RequestId>
    <HostId>Z2xAduhEswbdBqTB/cgCggm/jVG24dPZjy1GScs9ak0w95rF4I0SnDnJrUKHHQC</HostId>
</Error>
```

Here's the setting's we're using:

[image: Distribution Settings]
[image: Origin Settings]

And here's the policy for the bucket

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity *********"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::x***-logos/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Cache Behavior Settings - http://imgur.com/JBZqrRm

Comment: Make sure Cloudfront can read from the S3 bucket.

Comment: How would I enable or check this?

Comment: Origin settings, last option. See your screenshot. :)

Comment: I think I tried this earlier and it didn't work but I've just changed it again and it's in the process of distributing. I'll add the bucket's policy to my post :)

Comment: Have you set permissions on the objects to 'Everyone' -> 'read/download'?

Comment: I have yeah. They can be accessed fine via their S3 link. Just not via Cloudfront

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?

Comment: I haven't no. We moved away from AWS when they attempted to stiff us out of a ridiculous $600 for using a custom domain on Cloudfront.

Comment: $600 is for a HTTPS domain if you need more coverage than SNI. In any case, the "origin domain name" needs to be the **website** URL, such as bucketname.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com.

Comment: add `/index.html` in your url & check?

Answer (score 179):

If you're accessing the root of your CloudFront distribution, you need to set a default root object:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/DefaultRootObject.html

To specify a default root object using the CloudFront console:

- Sign in to the AWS Management Console and open the Amazon CloudFront console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/.
- In the list of distributions in the top pane, select the distribution to update.
- In the **Distribution Details pane**, on the **General** tab, click **Edit**.
- In the **Edit Distribution** dialog box, in the **Default Root Object** field, enter the file name of the default root object.

  Enter only the object name, for example, `index.html`. Do not add a / before the object name.
- To save your changes, click **Yes, Edit**.

Comment: In my case, this setting has not resolved the issue. I am still getting Access Denied error

Comment: oh god, why is this not in with any of the aws knowledge answers surrounding this topic! Thank you

Comment: For me, the _Alternative Domain_ configuration needed to be set to my domain name in the CloudFront configuration to resolve this issue.

Comment: Works in my case after specifying `index.html` as default root object, thanks!

Comment: In my case it was root object problem.

Answer (score 99):

I've just had the same issue and while Kousha's answer does solve the problem for *index.html* in the root path, my problem was also with sub-directories as I used those combined with *index.html* to get "pretty urls" (example.com/something/ rather than "ugly" example.com/something.html)

Partially it's Amazon's fault as well, because when you set up CloudFront distribution, it will offer you S3 buckets to choose from, but if you do choose one of those it will use the bucket URL rather than static website hosting URL as a backend.

So to fix the issue:

- Enable static website hosting for the bucket
- Set the *Index* (and perhaps *Error*) document appropriately
- Copy **Endpoint** URL - you can find it next to the above settings - It should look something like: *<bucket.name>.s3-website-<aws-region>.amazonaws.com*
- Use that URL as your CloudFront Distribution origin. (This will also make the CF *Default Root Object* setting unnecessary, but doesn't hurt to set it anyway)

UPDATE Jan '22: you can also fix this by keeping static hosting OFF and adding a CloudFront function to append `index.html`. See [this post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31017105/how-do-you-set-a-default-root-object-for-subdirectories-for-a-statically-hosted/69157535#69157535) for more information. This allows you to use an OAI and keep the bucket private.

Comment: Perfect answer as of the date on this comment.

Comment: That was it for me as well. I already had another website working and thought I configured the new one identically. So easy to overlook this.

Comment: You also need to add public GetObject and ListObjects permissions to the bucket.

Comment: @Georges how do you add public GetObject and ListObjects permissions to the bucket?

Comment: @Ryan you can check here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteAccessPermissionsReqd.html

Comment: Yeah, that was it for me.   The default bucket URL doesn't work well.  Needs to say "custom origin".  For more info see this post: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=314454

Comment: For me it was copying the url, not choosing the option provided by AWS.

Answer (score 19):

I had the same issue as @Cezz, though the solution would not work in my case.

As soon as static website hosting is enabled for the bucket, it means users can access the content either via the Cloudfront URL, or the S3 URL, which is not always desirable. For example, in my case, the Cloudfront distribution is SSL enabled, and users should not be able to access it over a non-SSL connection.

The solution I found was to:

- keep static website hosting disabled on the S3 bucket
- keep the Cloudfront distribution origin as an S3 ID
- set "Restrict Bucket Access" to "Yes" (and for ease, allow CloudFront to automatically update the bucket policy)
- on "Error Pages", create a custom response, and map error code "403: Forbidden" to the desired response page i.e. /index.html, with a response code of 200

Note though that in my case, I'm serving a single page javascript application where all paths are resolved by index.html. If you've paths that resolve to different objects in your S3 bucket, this will not work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This one worked for me. I had the same problem as you. I didn't want people to access my S3 bucket, so I needed to restrict access to the S3 Origin, which only works with when you fill in the origin as suggested by the auto-complete in Cloudfront. One side note though, you don't have to disable static website hosting. Simply removing the bucket policy which allows public access is enough.

Comment: This was really helpful, the forbidden message comes from S3 which I didn't realize at first, so you have to catch that with a custom error page so your SPA works.

Comment: This works for spas (eg react apps) withouts exposing the s3 bucket. Thank you.

Answer (score 12):

In my case I was using multiple origins with "Path Pattern" Behaviors along with an Origin Path in my S3 bucket:

### Bad setup:

CloudFront Behavior:
`/images/*` -> `My-S3-origin`

My-S3-origin:
Origin Path: `/images`

S3 files:
/images/my-image.jpg

GET Request:
/images/my-image.jpg -> 403

What was happening was the entire CloudFront GET request gets sent to the origin: `/image/my-image.jpg` prefixed by Origin Path: `/images`, so the request into S3 looks like `/images/images/my-image.jpg` which doesn't exist.

### Solution

remove Origin Path.

This allowed me to access the bucket with an origin access identity and bucket permissions and individual file permissions restricted.

Comment: On a related note, I had a CloudFront Distribution with two origins: set Cloudfront to `/video/*` -> My-S3-

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had configured Route 53 wrongly. I'd created an Alias on my domain but pointed it to the S3 Bucket instead of the CloudFront distribution.

Also I omitted the default root object. The console could really be improved if they add a bit of information to the question mark text about the potential consequences of omitting it.

Answer (score 1):

My issue was that I had turned website hosting off and had to change the origin name from the website path to the normal non-website one. That had removed the origin access identity. I put that back and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

If block public access is On and Hosting disabled, you need to setup Error Pages with appropriate HTTP error code and HTTP response code in CF.

Comment: Hi user2242291! Can you clarify how this builds on the other accepted answers?

Answer (score 0):

If your origin is setup with "Origin access control settings (recommended)"
Check that the origin has "Signing behavior" set to "Always sign requests".

Also, check that the provided policy has been added to the bucket on the "Permissions" tab.

Origin configuration:

[image]

Origin access configuration:

[image]