# Can't access static site S3, Cloudfront, Route53

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-s3, amazon-route53, amazon-cloudfront, static-content

I apologize if this needs to be split into two questions, but I'm trying to set up a static site using S3, a CloudFront distribution, and a Route53 domain. If I try to access laszloffy.com, I receive a DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN error. If I try [www.laszloffy.com](http://www.laszloffy.com), I get an XML 'Access Denied' error.

Below is my current configuration

**Route53 records:**

- laszloffy.com - NS
- laszloffy.com - SOA
- *.laszloffy.com - A - routes to Cloudfront distro
- *.laszloffy.com - AAAA - routes to https.....cloudfront.net
- ___.laszloffy.com - CNAME - routes to ____.acm-validations.aws

**CloudFront Distro:**

Alternate domain names:

- *.laszloffy.com
- laszloffy.com
  Default root object - index.html
  Origin:
- domain: slaszloffy-devops-resume.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
- path: /index.html
- OAC
  Error page:  403 to /index.html/200 status code
  Function: appends index.html to requests that don't included file name or extension in URL

**S3 Bucket**

- static site hosting: OFF
- bucket policy:

```
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowCloudFrontServicePrincipal",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "cloudfront.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::slaszloffy-devops-resume/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:cloudfront::107900886402:distribution/E1LP8SF6WAC8XK"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I've been looking through resources like [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/581268/amazon-cloudfront-with-s3-access-denied), and the AWS documentation, and it feels like I've got everything configured correctly, but obviously I'm missing something. Would love the community's assistance!

Answer (score 0):

Can you access the bucket directly with its ARN?
If yes..

Comment: What do you mean by 'start the route53'?

Comment: sorry.. some autocorrect that did that.
so.. can you access the bucket with its arn:aws:s3:::slaszloffy-devops-resume/ address? 
If that works. you have to fiddle with the Cloudfront.
also.. stop the AAA Pointer.. make A Pointer work first...then use AAA if necessary.